# "Site Pages" library was created automatically

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, administration, configuration, installation

I have an Enterprise wiki site collection inside my SharePoint enterprise server 2013. Today I accessed the site collection using SharePoint Designer. I just navigated through the site collection content, without adding or removing any component. Then I closed SharePoint Designer.

After that, I noticed that there is a new library named "Site Pages" have been automatically created as follows:

[image]

What could cause this library to be created and why would accessing my site collection using SharePoint Designer force this library to get created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: SitePages navigation link]

When you open site in SPD there's always Site Pages navigation node and it doesn't matter if you have Site Pages library currently or not.
But if you don't have it and just accidentally click on this navigation node it will be created by SPD without any prompt.

Comment: yes i think i click on the Site Pages,, but it is really strange who SPD will automatically create the library when clicking on it.. i thought since it is under the site Objects then it is already exists... now is there any drawbacks if i keep this library ?

Comment: Can't think of any real drawbacks. It's just a usual library. You can even hide it from UI if it bothers you so.

Answer (score 4):

'Site Pages' library will show up when you activate the 'Wiki Page Home Page' feature under the Manage Site Features in Site Settings. I am not sure if it has any link with designer though. Could be that the be two occurrences were independent.

Comment: i know that the "Site Pages" usually got created automatically when i activate some features at the site and site collection levels.. but in my case i did not activate any thing .. i just accessed the site collection using SPD as i mentioned before ... now is there a way to know exactly what causes this library to be created ?

Comment: May be the others two answers could be pointing to right direction. You can also check if the library got created by your name by using SharePoint Manager or with PowerShell

Comment: Yes i think the other replies is more realistic in my case

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you access "Site Pages" in SharePoint Designer, it will create the corresponding entry in the "Site Collection Contents".

Remember that you can hide that list entry from Contents using SharePoint Designer:

Select properties under All Files node:
[image: Select under All Files]

Then check the "hide from browser" option & save.
[image: Then check the "hide from browser" option]

Comment: this is the first time i know this info , that when I click on a library inside SPD it will get automatically created for me !!! without even getting any prompt if i like to add it or not !!.. now i can keep it as is ,, will it cause any problem?

Comment: No, it doesn't causes any problem, but just be sure to set the right permission levels for your users, and if you're not going to use it, it's better to hide it from browser.